# Can't create customized table

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to create a table where I can add rows and columns dynamically that are of type textbox or by taking user input.

then I tried using Tables but now I can control only rows not columns .

```
        table1 = new Table();
        TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
        TableRow row = new TableRow();

        trg1.Rows.Add(row);
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        para.Inlines.Add(tbx);
        TableCell cell = new TableCell(para);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

---

I tried doing it on DataGrid in wpf but I can only control column number not rows.

```
          myGrid.Columns.Clear();

           ObservableCollection<EmptyCell> collection = new ObservableCollection<EmptyCell>();
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            DataGridTemplateColumn dtg = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            dtg.CanUserResize = true;
            dtg.IsReadOnly = false;
            dtg.CellTemplate = getDataTemplate();

            myGrid.CanUserAddRows = true;
            myGrid.ItemsSource = collection; 
            myGrid.Columns.Add(dtg);
        }
   }
    private static DataTemplate getDataTemplate()
    {
        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        factory.SetValue(TextBox.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);
      template.VisualTree = factory;

        return template;
    }
```

Comment: I usually use a DataTable.  A DataTable can be dynamically created and rows can be dynamically added. The DataTable can be use as the DataSource or binding for your controls.

Comment: Thats the point , I don't want to bind it.It has to be empty like tables in wordpad.

Comment: Explain better.  You comment make absolutely not sense.  How can you bind to something that is empty?  I assume you mean an empty DataTable.  You can dynamically create the columns in a DataTable and then later add rows as required.

Comment: what I mean is, as you can see in the code above I made each cell a textbox.
there is no data to begin with.the table I am creating will take input from users,and don't even have to save it .

Comment: With any table or grid you add one row at a time.  The last row is where new data is entered.  The form DataGridView has an option to allow editing and when that property is set a new blank row is created when new data is entered into the previous last row.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to use a 2 dimensional array as a datasource, and bind it to an `itemsControl` (for rows) which has an embedded `ItemsControl` inside its `ItemTemplate` (for columns).

With this kind of solution you can add additional rows/columns by just adding to the 2 dimensional array, and re-binding (if its not based on `INotifyColectionChanged` data datastructures)